# How to hide sensitive data in logs generated by apache

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot app which needs to log everything so I've put it on DEBUG level but the thing is that I need to hide sensitive data from incoming requests
For example I see logs like this one:

```
2020-09-22 12:07:27,626 DEBUG 3484 --- [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer]: Received [POST /rest/api/authenticate/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.5
Postman-Token: ac1ae730-5f56-48b0-b73c-0225b681a85e
Host: localhost:8988
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 75

{
  "email": "test",
  "password": "test"
}]
```

I need to hide the test values from email and password  . Are there any ways to do that? i've seen only how to disable Http11InputBuffer

Answer (score 0):

It would be best not to send username and password in the body(based on the example log given here), please make use of authorization.
Also attaching a post that could be helpful : [Hiding sensitive/confidential information in log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466905/hiding-sensitive-confidential-information-in-log-files)